# I want check data with VLookup and with different cells

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have to if cells in another excel sheet in a different excel sheet has can be found and has "1st" in the Text ins results, and the cell has to equal to "TF2".
Here is the bug it just errors when not finding an entry
`=IF([2021_03_01Selections.xlsx]ATRTF_2!$A1="","",IFERROR(IF(AND(LEFT(VLOOKUP("*"&[2021_03_01Selections.xlsx]ATRTF_2!$B1&"*",[2021_03_01Selections.xlsx]Results!$A:$A,1,0),3)="1st",RIGHT([2021_03_01Selections.xlsx]ATRTF_2!$C1,3)="TF1"),"W",IF(AND(LEFT(VLOOKUP("*"&[2021_03_01Selections.xlsx]ATRTF_2!$D1&"*",[2021_03_01Selections.xlsx]Results!$A:$A,1,0),3)="1st",RIGHT([2021_03_01Selections.xlsx]ATRTF_2!$E1,3)="TF1"),"W",IF(AND(LEFT(VLOOKUP("*"&[2021_03_01Selections.xlsx]ATRTF_2!$F1&"*",[2021_03_01Selections.xlsx]Results!$A:$A,1,0),3)="1st",[2021_03_01Selections.xlsx]ATRTF_2!$G1="TF1"),"W","L"))),"L"))`

I then tried the below, but in the if it finds an entry and its not "1st" then it goes to "L" this would mean repeating all the formulas again an false.

`=IF([2021_02_21Selections.xlsx]ATRTF_2!$A13="","",IFERROR( IF(AND(RIGHT([2021_02_21Selections.xlsx]ATRTF_2!$C13,3)="TF2",LEFT(VLOOKUP("*"&[2021_02_21Selections.xlsx]ATRTF_2!$B13&"*",[2021_02_21Selections.xlsx]Results!$A:$A,1,0),3)="1st"),"W","L"), IFERROR(IF(AND(RIGHT([2021_02_21Selections.xlsx]ATRTF_2!$E13,3)="TF2",LEFT(VLOOKUP("*"&[2021_02_21Selections.xlsx]ATRTF_2!$D13&"*",[2021_02_21Selections.xlsx]Results!$A:$A,1,0),3)="1st"),"W","L"), IFERROR(IF(AND(RIGHT([2021_02_21Selections.xlsx]ATRTF_2!$G13,3)="TF2",LEFT(VLOOKUP("*"&[2021_02_21Selections.xlsx]ATRTF_2!$F13&"*",[2021_02_21Selections.xlsx]Results!$A:$A,1,0),3)="1st"),"W","L"), IFERROR(IF(AND(RIGHT([2021_02_21Selections.xlsx]ATRTF_2!$I13,3)="TF2",LEFT(VLOOKUP("*"&[2021_02_21Selections.xlsx]ATRTF_2!$H13&"*",[2021_02_21Selections.xlsx]Results!$A:$A,1,0),3)="1st"),"W","L"),"L")))))`
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I think I would restructure the data into a small table then work from there.

Comment: @Solar Mike I cannot the data is not mine, the data is in dated excel workbooks